# Can I write one SQL statement based on a property value?

Tags: sql, database

I was wondering if I could write one SQL statement or if I will have to write many different SQL statements using the control flow of the application.

Essentially, I have a table called Students that will have a column sex(M,F).

I also have a table called Divisions that will have a column named sex(null, M, F). If the value is null, I want to retrieve all students, both male and female.

I know I can write two different statements to get this job done. But, I have other columns that will work the same way and I was wondering if there is a way I could write one statement rather then 10.

Comment: I would suggest creating a stored procedure and add a parameter for filtering by sex. I think that a new table just to store a column with a single row is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just make sure your join condition does what you ask:
Something like this (untested)

```
select * from students s left outer join division d on (s.sex=d.sex or d.sex is null)
```

Comment: Replying to a now missing comment about using UNION for performance: Unless there's a reason to suspect otherwise, write the most clear, logical thing that works and measure it if it matters.  There's no reason a union would be faster at all. I can think of a few reasons why it might be slower.  It depends on how capable the optimiser is.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're looking for something like this (T-SQL since you didn't mention what you're using):

```
select *
from students, divisions
where (divisions.sex is not null and students.sex=divisions.sex) or (divisions.sex is null)
```

Comment: Do note that as written this doesn't make much sense, it will select everything as long as any division row has the field set to `null`. But your initial question makes just as much sense unless you specifically select one division -- this is where this starts making sense. Ie besides that condition, you have `and division.name='..'` or something.